# Qt Visual C++ Add-in No Default Version Found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I am at my wit's end trying to configre Qt. I have finally got it built with MSVC++2010, but I'm having trouble with the add-in. I'm getting the "no default version found" error despite the fact that I have set a path to what I believe to be the right place in C:\Users\Aaron\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2\qtbase

Is this the correct place? If not, what file am I trying to link VSC++ to? Is it the qmake?

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, i've updated visual stupidity, and removed the old plugin and readded it, still no dice. It's incredibly annoying. No MingW joy either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your qt build for `qmake.exe`.  The path to that file is what the Qt Add-on is looking for.

You might also need to end it with a backslash.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtVSAddin

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, but its still giving me problems. I found two qmake.exe. One said it was an invalid version (wasn't compiled with VSC++ or something). The other worked fine when set as default version. But, if I try to make a new Qt file of any kind it gives me an error "no default version found" all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my problem was that I had the wrong version of Qt installed. I was using everywhere-Qtopensource. I downloaded Qt for VS2010 and linked the add-in to that version's makefile and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was I was adding the wrong directory, I tried to add the bin directory, then i tried to add the QT directory. The directory to be added is the C:\QT\QT5\5.7\msvc2013_64 directory, or whatever they are calling it today.

Note I had to update visual stupidity, then install the latest "QT visual studio tools".

Then I found that these studio tools don't have the core QT build utilities - such as qmake, for instances, so I had to install the QT Unified installer for windows, then be sure that the MSVC 20xx 64 bit version is selected. I didn't need the rest of it, and i certainly don't need 58GB of garbage.